# Hiding option in dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, hidden

I'm trying to selectively hide options in a dropdown list using the 'hidden' attribute. Please take a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFK3K/176/) in which I hide the 'quietest' option.

```
$('#quietest').prop('hidden', 'hidden');
```

When clicking the arrows on the dropdown list the 'quietest' option is successfully hidden (only 'fastest' and 'balanced' are listed), however, the user can still select the 'quietest' option by using the keyboard. Is that expected behavior for the 'hidden' attribute? How to properly hide so it's no longer selectable? It needs to be easy to unhide the option as well (so preferably no removing of the option).

Comment: You'd use `.show()/.hide()` or `.toggle()`. There are issues with hiding options in certain browsers though. You'd be better off just enabling/disabling the option using `.prop('disabled', true|false)`

Comment: @chiapa solution will work for you if you want to prevent the option from selecting rather hiding. But still the disabled option will show in the dropdown. If you want to acquire both try removing the option when you want and appending when you need to show it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this:

[Fiddle - hiding with `hidden` property](http://jsfiddle.net/dFK3K/179/)

```js
$('#quietest').prop('disabled', true).prop('hidden', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dptcentres_edit">
    <option value="fastest">Fastest</option>
    <option selected="true" value="balanced">Balanced</option>
    <option id='quietest' value="quietest">Quietest</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

Due to @billyonecan's comment, I replaced the hiding method, instead of using the `hidden` property, I use the CSS `display` attribute and set it to none in order to hide the element. As he correctly states, the `hidden` property [isn't supported by all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=hidden).

[Fiddle - Hiding with CSS `display` attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/dFK3K/180/)

```js
$('#quietest').prop('disabled', true).css('display', 'none');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dptcentres_edit">
    <option value="fastest">Fastest</option>
    <option selected="true" value="balanced">Balanced</option>
    <option id='quietest' value="quietest">Quietest</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You'd be better off using `.hide()`, the `hidden` attribute [isn't supported by all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=hidden)

Comment: Be aware that you can still type on the keyboard and select values that are hidden. See Raja's answer.

Comment: With Microsoft Edge, both Fiddle show a blank space instead of hidden option. Works fine with Chrome. (Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0)

Answer (score 3):

To stop being selected, add `disabled` as well

```
$('#quietest').prop('disabled', true).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `hide`. By hiding the `option`, it cannot be selected.

```
$('#quietest').hide().prop('disable', true);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/dFK3K/177/)

Comment: This still have the problem. You can select the quietest by arrow key.